# Adding Basic Text to Win32 App, c++

Tags: c++, winapi, text, tic-tac-toe

So i am making a tic tac toe game (I am a just barely beginning, and this is my first ever attempt to do anything windows), and i want to have a section where the game can keep score.  I can't figure out how to add simple text to the window, like the word "SCORE" so i can put the score underneath it in a fancy little table.  I have figured out how to make a text window using the following code:

```
    CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("PLAYER 1"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 20,250,100,25,hWnd,HMENU(NULL),GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("PLAYER 2"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 130,250,100,25,hWnd,HMENU(NULL),GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

That is useful to me for the names because the players can go in and edit the text boxes to put in their own names (if there is a better way to do this i would appreciate any tips here too).  But really my question is can i make a window like this to display text that CAN'T be edited by the user?

Comment: Use `"STATIC"` as the class name. There's also `ES_READONLY`, but I don't think that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok cool thanks thats works!  I do kind of have a second question though if you could help, is there a way to auto center the text in the box?  Or do i have to kind of center it myself using spaces and what not...

Comment: [`SS_CENTER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much chris.

Comment: Well, it doesn't feel like much, but it does answer the question, so I guess I'd better make it one, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "EDIT" class name is for edit controls. You're looking for more of a label, and that is offered through the "STATIC" class name, along with support for an icon or bitmap rather than text.

As for the later question of how to centre it, it's one of the many [static-control-specific styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use. The one in particular you're looking for is `SS_CENTER`, which can be bitwise-ORed with your two `WS_*` styles.